# Google Code Jam - New Lottery Game

Tags: code-golf

I was looking around on the web and I found this Google Code Jam Puzzle. I really liked it so I decided to post it here.

> #### New Lottery Game
>
> The Lottery is changing! The Lottery used to have a machine to
>   generate a random winning number. But due to cheating problems, the
>   Lottery has decided to add another machine. The new winning number
>   will be the result of the bitwise-AND operation between the two random
>   numbers generated by the two machines.
>
> To find the bitwise-AND of *X* and *Y*, write them both in binary; then a
>   bit in the result in binary has a 1 if the corresponding bits of *X* and
>   Y were both 1, and a 0 otherwise. In most programming languages, the
>   bitwise-AND of *X* and *Y* is written *X&Y*.
>
> For example:    The old machine generates the number *7 = 0111*.    The
>   new machine generates the number *11 = 1011*.    The winning number will
>   be *(7 AND 11) = (0111 AND 1011) = 0011 = 3*.
>
> With this measure, the Lottery expects to reduce the cases of
>   fraudulent claims, but unfortunately an employee from the Lottery
>   company has leaked the following information: the old machine will
>   always generate a non-negative integer less than *A* and the new one
>   will always generate a non-negative integer less than *B*.
>
> Catalina wants to win this lottery and to give it a try she decided to
>   buy all non-negative integers less than *K*.
>
> Given *A*, *B* and *K*, Catalina would like to know in how many different
>   ways the machines can generate a pair of numbers that will make her a
>   winner.
>
> Could you help her?
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T lines
>   follow, each line with three numbers A B K.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x: y", where x
>   is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of
>   possible pairs that the machines can generate to make Catalina a
>   winner.
>
> **Limits**
>
> 1 ≤ *T* ≤ 100. Small dataset
>
> 1 ≤ *A* ≤ 1000. 1 ≤ *B* ≤ 1000. 1 ≤ *K* ≤ 1000. Large dataset
>
> 1 ≤ *A* ≤ 109. 1 ≤ *B* ≤ 109. 1 ≤ *K* ≤ 109. Sample
>
> ```
> Input                 Output
> 5                     Case #1: 10
> 3 4 2                 Case #2: 16
> 4 5 2                 Case #3: 52
> 7 8 5                 Case #4: 2411
> 45 56 35              Case #5: 14377
> 103 143 88
> ```
>
> In the first test case, these are the 10 possible pairs generated by
>   the old and new machine respectively that will make her a winner:
>   <0,0>, <0,1>, <0,2>, <0,3>, <1,0>, <1,1>, <1,2>, <1,3>, <2,0> and
>   <2,1>. Notice that <0,1> is not the same as <1,0>. Also, although the
>   pair <2, 2> could be generated by the machines it wouldn't make
>   Catalina win since *(2 AND 2) = 2* and she only bought the numbers 0 and
>   1.

Here's the link for actual problem: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2994486/dashboard#s=p1

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.
Good Luck

Comment: Is a trailing newline optional and a leading newline allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Ruby, 107

I expected this would be a much shorter program.

```ruby
gets
loop{a,b,k=gets.split.map &:to_i
puts"Case ##{$.-1}: #{[*0...a].product([*0...b]).count{|x,y|x&y<k}}"}
```

### Explanation

- The first line of input can be ignored.
- `$.` is the last read line number.
- `[*0...x]` is a quick way to turn the `Range` into an `Array`. It uses the splat operator (`*`). Note that the `Range` is an exclusive one (`...` instead of `..`).
- `Array#count` takes a block. It will only count the elements for which the block returns a truthy value.

Comment: Any chance you can do `$<.map{...}`?

Comment: It's actually two characters longer, because it has to take an argument.

Answer (score 2):

### APL (63)

It's the I/O that costs a lot.

```
↑{a b k←¯1+⍳¨⎕⋄'Case #',(⍕⍵),': ',⍕+/∊k∊⍨a∘.{2⊥∧/⍺⍵⊤⍨10/2}b}¨⍳⎕
```

Explanation:

- `{`...`}¨⍳⎕`: read a number N from the keyboard, and run the following function for each number from 1 to N.
- `a b k←¯1+⍳¨⎕`: read three numbers from the keyboard, generate a list from 0..n-1 for each, and store these in `a`, `b`, and `k`.
- `a∘.{`...`}b`: for each combination of values from `a` and `b`:

  - `⍺⍵⊤⍨10/2`: get the 10-bit binary representation for both values (this is enough given the limits)
  - `∧/`: *and* together all pairs of bits
  - `2⊤`: turn it back into a number
- `k∊⍨`: for each of these values, test if it is in `k`
- `+/`: sum the result
- `'Case #',(⍕⍵),': ',⍕`: generate the output string for this case
- `↑`: turn the result into a matrix, so each string ends up on a separate line.

Test:

```
      ↑{a b k←¯1+⍳¨⎕⋄'Case #',(⍕⍵),': ',⍕+/∊k∊⍨a∘.{2⊥∧/⍺⍵⊤⍨10/2}b}¨⍳⎕
⎕:
      5
⎕:
      3 4 2
⎕:
      4 5 2
⎕:
      7 8 5
⎕:
      45 56 35
⎕:
      103 143 88
Case #1: 10   
Case #2: 16   
Case #3: 52   
Case #4: 2411 
Case #5: 14377
```

Answer (score 1):

### Golfscript - <strike>74</strike> 64

Here is my Golfscript solution (could probably be improved):

```
n/(;0:m;{[~0:w.{{.2$&3$<w+:w;)}4$*;)0}5$*];'Case #'m):m': 'w n}%
```

Here is the pseudocode I used for this:

```
Split string at newlines
Get rid of first element (this is not needed, as I am looping through each element anyway)
Let m=0 (case #)
For each group of 3 numbers A, B, and K:
  Let w=0 (number of winning combinations)
  For(C,0,A-1)
    For(D,0,B-1)
      If (A&B)<K
        Let w=w+1 (one more winning combination)
      End
    End
  End
  Let m=m+1 (case # incremented)
  Output("Case #",m,": ",w,"/n")
End
```

Assumes valid input.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam - 62

Could probably be improved; this is just a port of my Golfscript answer.

```
qN/(;{[~0_{{_2$&3$<V+:V;)}4$*;)0}5$*];"Case #"T):T": "V0:V;N}%
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 145

I'm still learning Ruby, so there's probably a shorter way to do this.

```
(1..gets.to_i).each{|_|a,b,k=gets.split.map{|x|x.to_i};x=0;(0...k).each{|i|(0...a).each{|j|(0...b).each{|k|x+=1 if j&k==i}}};p"Case ##{_}: #{x}"}
```

**Ungolfed**:

```
( 1 .. gets.to_i ).each{ | _ |
    a, b, k = gets.split.map{ | x | x.to_i }
    x = 0

    ( 0 ... k ).each{ | i |
        ( 0 ... a ).each{ | j |
            ( 0 ... b ).each{ | k |
                x += 1 if j & k == i
            }
        }
    }

    p "Case ##{_}: #{x}"
}
```

Comment: Looping with `#map` is one character shorter than with `#each`. You don't need to loop trough `0...k`, you can simply check if the binary and is lower than `k`. When you're only calling a method without arguments in a block you can use `Symbol#to_proc` (`x.map &:to_i`).

Answer (score 0):

### J, 90 (70)

I/O to stdin/stdout, works as a script (**90**).

```j
,&LF@('Test #'&,)"1@(":@#,{:)\@:}.@:(': '&,"1)@(+/@,@(>`(17 b./&i.)/@|.)&.".;._2)&.stdin''
```

Input on stdin, output implicit in REPL (akin to APL, I believe) (**70**).

```j
'Test #',"1(":@#,{:)\}.': ',"1+/@,@(>`(17 b./&i.)/@|.)&.".;._2 stdin''
```

Ergh, J isn't good at I/O requirements like these.

For the curious, the part doing the heavy work is `` +/@,@(>`(17 b./&i.)/@|.)&.". ``, which solves a single line of the problem (taking and returning a string).

Answer (score 0):

### CJAM - 57

```
0li{)"Case #"\':Sl~:K;L\{(2$,{1$&@+\}%~}h;\;{K<},,N4$}\*;
```

I think this can be golfed further.

```
0                                  acts as a counter for the case #
  li{                              accepts the first line of input as integer/opens block
     )                             iterates counter
      "Case #"\':S                 adds "Case #X: " to stack (though in 4 parts)
       l~:K;L\                     takes next line of input, assign K, add null array
         {
          (2$,                     decrease B and generate list of number <A
           {
            1$&                    Copy the current value of B, do & with current n<A
             @+\                   Add the new possible lottery number to array
           }%~                     loop for each element if the list of numbers <A
         }h                        loop which repeats for all numbers less than B
       ;/;{K<},,                   trim and count the possible numbers less than K
      N4$                          add new line and copy the counter back in place
  }\*                              runs the block T times
;                                  removes the counter so it doesn't print
```

Output:

```
Case #1: 10
Case #2: 16
Case #3: 52
Case #4: 2411
Case #5: 14377
```

Comment: li{"Case #"]_,6/)+~':Sl~:K;L\{(2$,{1$&@+\}%~}h;\;{K<},,N}\*           for fun, this does the same thing but instead of having a counter for case#, it counts the number of elements in the stack.